# Why doesn't mutable.Map extend immutable.Map?

Tags: scala

This code works:

```
@ mutable.Seq(1, 2).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]
res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
```

But this doesn't:

```
@ mutable.Map(1 -> 2).asInstanceOf[Map[Int, Int]]
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap cannot be cast
to scala.collection.immutable.Map
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.<init>(cmd1.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd1$.<clinit>(cmd1.sc)
```

Why can `mutable.Seq` be viewed as immutable, but not `mutable.Map`? I understand that casting a mutable `Seq` to an immutable one is "lying" about the mutability of the underlying collection, but in some situations the programmer knows better—e.g. when returning a collection from a function which uses a mutable list to build up a result, but returns an immutable value.

Comment: Not sure about the "why", but if you want to convert a mutable map into an immutable one, use `mutableMap.toMap`; Same goes to `mutableSeq.toSeq` - this way you need not know anything about the underlying implementation.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/g_-gIWgB8Os (found from [The default Scala Seq is mutable](https://orrsella.com/2014/02/27/the-default-scala-seq-is-mutable-wait-what/) ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `Map` is defined in [`Predef`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html) as

```
type Map[A, +B] = collection.immutable.Map[A, B]
```

so it is explicitly `immutable`, and `mutable.Map` is not a subclass of it.

In contrast to that, the default `Seq` is defined directly in [`scala`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/index.html) as

```
type Seq[+A] = scala.collection.Seq[A]
```

so it is a supertype of both `mutable.Seq` and `immutable.Seq`. This is why your first `asInstanceOf` does not fail: every `mutable.Seq` is also a `collection.Seq`.

As explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/g_-gIWgB8Os), the decision to not specify whether `Seq` has to be mutable or immutable had something to do with support for arrays and varargs.

[In 2.13, the default `Seq` will become `immutable`, and a new type `ImmutableArray` will be introduced to deal with `varargs`.](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/02/28/collections-rework.html#language-integration) (Thanks @SethTisue for pointing it out)

Comment: the `Seq` in `Predef` will be changed to point to `collection.immutable.Seq` in Scala 2.13

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks for pointing it out, I've added a (hopefully relevant) link to `scala-lang.org` about that change.

Comment: Ah, too bad—it was really convenient to be able to build up a result as an `ArrayBuffer` and return it as a `Seq` without copying it into a new immutable structure!

Comment: @nornagon "convenient" in the same sense as selling the soul to Devil for some short-term gratification is "convenient"? ;) If you don't want to copy anything into immutable structure, declare the return type explicitly as `mutable.Seq`, and everything is almost as it was before. Imho, there shouldn't be any collections in the language spec whatsoever. Instead of `Seq` or `ImmutableArray`, the `vararg` mechanism should be a polymorphic function `A* := [B](B, (B, A) => B) => B` or something like that... Unfortunately, these functions are not in the core of Scala...

Comment: If an element of an array changes in the forest, but nobody's around to observe it, is it really mutable? 

Comment: @nornagon As long as there is also a guarantee that nobody will ever be able to observe it, it's referentially transparent, which is good enough. As long as there could potentially be someone who can observe the mutation, it's not referentially transparent. If it's just not mutated, it's rather a convention.

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is this:

If `scala.collection.mutable.Map` was a subclass of `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, then the former *is-a* latter too. That is, a *mutable* `Map` is also *immutable*. Does that make sense?

To illustrate this, you could pass an instance of a *mutable* `Map` to a function or constructor expecting an *immutable* `Map`. Alas, the two types have different semantics: if you, say, add an element to the *immutable* version, you'll get a new *immutable* `Map` instance returned; yet if you add an element to the *mutable* version, it changes that instance's contents—thus, it will have a *side-effect*.

As a consequence, if you wanted to write a *pure, referentially transparent* (*RT*) function (i.e. one that has no *side-effects*) that takes an *immutable* `Map` argument, you couldn't achieve your goal—anyone could screw that up by passing it a *mutable* `Map` instance instead. This would then change the meaning of your code and potentially cause all manner of problems.

In *functional programming*, *immutability* is big deal, as is *RT*. By ensuring that the two cannot be confused, programs that need *immutable* `Map`s can guarantee that they will get them.

(Of course, if you explicitly want to write code that will accept either, you could request an instance of their common `scala.collection.Map` trait instead.)